# Rails 3 Rails Console Test.new doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

I created a scaffold in Rails 3 and ran the migration. But when I tried to use the rails console to create an instance of the model, it doesn't work. I repeated the same process in Rails 4 and it works perfectly.
Here is the commands I typed in.

rails new testApp
rails g scaffold Test name:string
rake db:migrate
rails console
p = Test.new

and below is the response I got:
1.9.3p194 :002 > p = Test.new
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Test:Module
    from (irb):2
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in`start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in`'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in`'

Please help. I am a beginner in rails. Thank you.

Comment: Your rake db:migrate went through with no problem in Rails 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test` is a module of Unit testing. When you type it in console, this constant get shown instead of your own model.

The only lesson is to avoid using sensitive names in your app's constant names.

Comment: Thank you. I will try again with a different name.

Comment: Yes, changing the name to Status actually works on rails 3. I have another question. Why does Test work in rails 4 and not rails 3. I created a test model in rails 4, and it works on rails console. Thank you.

Comment: In rails 4, you probably just got lucky.  It's related to the class loader and order of operations.  If, by some means, your Test model class get's loaded first, then it'll win.  Rails4 may have changed the class loading order which might make that poorly named class, `Test` load before the Unit test version which could conflict.

Answer (score 0):

For a full list of reserved keywords check out: 
http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/